Logging the Microsoft OData Connected service api call to an odata endpoint?
For debugging purposes, I would like to log the actual http call to an OData endpoint. I am using the Microsoft OData Client V8.0.1 and the OData Connected Service 2022+ (v1.1.0) extension to auto generate the context.
What is the simplest way to log the actual http call? Is there a configuration setting in the OData Client or other way to get the calls to print out to the console or a logging provider?
